# Problem in adding new site on WP multisite

Tags: multisite, database, collation

It's for two or three months that this problem exists in WordPress multisite and I'm still waiting for a solution or an update.

When adding new site, I get this error:

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
> in wp-includes/formatting.php on line
> 3435
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
> in wp-includes/formatting.php on line
> 3424
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
> in wp-includes/formatting.php on line
> 3435
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
> in wp-includes/formatting.php on line
> 3407
>
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
> in wp-includes/formatting.php on line
> 3407
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
> to string in wp-includes/kses.php on
> line 1038

Have anybody found a safe solution for this without making any threat to the database?

I've already found some suggestions on [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-not-add-new-site-wpmu/). They say we should change the value of:

```
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

to:

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_general_ci');
```

Is it safe for our website?

We have lots of posts on our website and we don't want to make any problem for our database and website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in the next update of WordPress. By the way if you still haven't updated your version of WordPress:

It's enough to set DB_COLLATE in the wp-config.php:

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_general_ci'); // on condition that your DB_CHARSET is 'utf8mb4'
```

That's it!

The bug is hidden in the file \wp-includes\wp-db.php on the line 731 in the function init_charset(). For multisite mode the 'utf8_general_ci' collation is used if DB_COLLATE is empty. And if your DB_CHARSET is 'utf8mb4' then the error occures.

The actual error is raised when creating and consequently querying nonexistent tables for the new site ('2' changes with the number of sites):

wp_2_terms

wp_2_term_taxonomy

wp_2_term_relationships

wp_2_commentmeta

wp_2_comments

wp_2_links

wp_2_options

wp_2_postmeta

wp_2_posts

[someone suggested this solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-not-add-new-site-wpmu/page/2#post-6995310) and it works fine.

Comment: While the link might answer the question, you should include the essential parts of the answer here and only provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added the details. Thanks for reminding.